# Godot I can't change position when changing scenes

Tags: godot

I'm just trying to learn Godot. I went through the door and changed the scene, but when I come back through the door, it puts my position in a different position instead of in front of the door. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8QNUCmmf5c I'm trying to implement the codes in this video.

```
func _ready():
    print(Game.door_name)
    
    # code for finding the door:
    if Game.door_name:
        var door_node = find_child(Game.door_name)
        if door_node:
            $Player.global_position = door_node.global_position
            print(door_node.global_position)
            print($Player.global_position)
```

output of the code
Door2
(2233, 398)
(2233, 398)

Since Godot 3 is used in this video, I used the find_child code instead of the find_node code. To test the code, I get the door_node's location and player location correctly with the print code, but my character appears in a different place.

Comment: First guess without seeing enough (you really should add images or descripe the problem better): If your door is simply a sprite the default setting puts the image centered around it position. Your player is a KinematicBody2D I assume. So there default position is in the top left corner. so there might be a difference if you sprite in character is not not centered